# Equation(s) of a curve having constraints in $0$ and $\pm \infty$

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

i would like to find an equation that can generate the following function:

[image: Link to image due to low reputation]

The equation needs to have the following characteristics:

- limit to -inf has to tend to -inf,-inf linearly
- limit to +inf has to tend to +inf,+inf linearly
- Has to have 3 turning points as pointed out in the image as to create the "step"-like feature
- limit to -0 of the first derivative has to tend to 0
- limit to +0 of the first derivative has to tend to +inf.

It can of course be a system of 2 equations (for x<0 and x>0), but if it could be merged into one (with an abs i.e) that would be great!

Comment: How important is it to have one formula? My gut feeling is that this problem would be easiest if you allowed for at least four formulas: one formula from $-\infty$ to where it stops being linear, then another formula from that point to $0$, then yet another formula from $0$ to where it becomes linear again, and the last formula from that point on to $+\infty$.

Comment: Poor, uninformative title.  Fix it so it refers to the content of your question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Done. Can you please remove the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is a solution gluing two quarter branches of a hyperbola:

$$\begin{cases}y&=&1-\sqrt{x^2+1}&x<0\\
y&=&\sqrt{x^2+2x}&x\ge 0\end{cases}$$

Their common asymptote has equation $y=x+1$.

Comment: The negative part is not exactly as i needed, but i can work with this too. Thanks.